# How can I deal with a star a repository error with GitHub api?

Tags: swift, github-api, put

I'm trying to star/unstar repository with the GitHub REST API, but it isn't working properly.

According to the document, I should use PUT to star a repository.

[image: Swift Code]

But it isn't working; the response is always `Not Found 404`.

The URL is not wrong.
I renewed my access token but is still not working.
I made another account, set Content-Length as 0 in the header but it still doesn't work.
I tried with other repositories but it's still not working. And When I create a new account accessToken, I checked all of the scopes, doesn't work either. Also, Unstar (delete) sends the same response too.
Not found 404. All the other API calls work fine.
[image]

Please help.

Comment: Please include code, not pictures of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As mentioned, we much prefer (and will ask) to see [properly formatted code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) rather than images of code. Also, I recommend you provide a [mre] rather than copy-paste your exact source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you tried to attach your owner and repository as query parameters.

If you are referring to [this API call](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#star-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user) (`PUT /user/starred/{owner}/{repo}`), then  you need to include them as positional parameters instead. Update your `url`:

```swift
let url = URL(string: 
  "https://api.github.com/user/starred/\(repoModel.ownerName)/\(repoModel.repoName)"
);
```